# How to create a loop to extract rows based on condition from character string

Tags: r, extract

Looking to extract rows from a large data frame based on whether the row contains any of the datetime stamps listed in a character string and add them to a new data frame.

Example data frame and character string of datetime stamps.

```r
df <- data.frame(
    Date = c("2017/05/10 15:00", "2017/05/10 22:00", "2017/05/25 10:00", "2017/05/25 20:00"), 
    value = c(15, 10, 25, 7)
)
df$Date <- as.POSIXlt(df$Date, tz ="GMT", origin = '1970-01-01')

dtlist <- c("2017/05/10 22:00", "2017/05/25 20:00") # desired datetimes
```

Looking for output like this:

```
Date                 Value
2017/05/10 22:00      10
2017/05/25 20:00      7
```

First thought was to use `which()` to identify the rows but don't know how to incorporate the condition of reading the variables from dtlist.

e.g. `which(df$value == dtlist(i))` where i is nth object in the list

Comment: Convert all date times to `POSIXct` and use `%in%` with ISO datetime format: `YYYY-MM-DD`. What is `i`? Please post full code not line snippets.

Comment: Date times are in POSIXct form in dataset (which can't be uploaded since it contains 350k rows with sensitive data). How would you use %in% to extract the rows? The e.g. line wasn't a snippet, I was trying to show what I was meaning as I'm struggling to find the right way to describe it. Perhaps this would be more accurate a representation:  (i=1:length(dtlist){which(df$value == i)}

Comment: `POSIXct` does not display with forward slashes and shows timezones. But if so, again try `%in%` on your list: `sub_df <- df[df$Date %in% dtlist,]`.